# RVM can't install ruby-2.2.4 but can install other (newer) versions

Tags: ruby, rvm

I’m unable to install Ruby version 2.2.4 using RVM, however, 2.7.0 and 2.6.3 install file. I’ll note that when I run this command `gem install bundler` or `gem update —-system`, i get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

And before this gets marked as a duplicate question, because there are a lot of answers solving this exact problem, they’re all answers posted before 2013 and are thus outdated. When I try running their solution, rvm gives me a warning that what I’m doing is considered deprecated use of RVM.

It’s also probably worth mentioning that when I try to install ruby 2.2.4,  I get this error:

```
ruby-2.2.4 - #installing rubygems-3.0.8 - please wait
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/garcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global GEM_PATH= /Users/garcia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -d /Users/garcia/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/garcia/.rvm/log/1583159172_ruby-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log
```

I already submitted an issue ticket on the RVM repo, but no one has responded in the last 3 days.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is your problem solved ? I am also facing same issue

Comment: @sunil I ended up switching to rbenv.

Comment: I am using catlina macOs but rbenv does not provide 2.2.4 version can u help me in it ?

Comment: @sunil I'm also using MacOS Catalina, and switching to rbenv solved pretty much everything for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby version < 2.4 require the old and insecure OpenSSL 1.0 and is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.1. Check the links below on how to install it:

`brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0`

- **RVM**: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4781#issuecomment-608623532
- **rbenv**: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353#issuecomment-573414540
- **chruby**: https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/363#issuecomment-580699347
- **asdf** already works, but has instructions too: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/wiki/Ruby-Installation-Problems

`gem install bundler -v '~>1'`

Comment: For those who don't like to click, here is RVM: `rvm reinstall 2.2.4 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have openssl installed? please use following command to check it

```
openssl
```

There are some issue of compatibility between versions for different rubies. Ruby <2.4 is incompatible with OpenSSL 1.1 that mean you should have OpenSSL 1.0 you have to look in your folders for version 1 and check its folder and try following command where I have put option of --with-openssl-dir

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.4 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d
```

In case you can't find openssl you can try this, but be caution as this openssl stuff is complicated and can effect other softwares too.

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Please check this url may help you to understand [How to fix ruby openssl](https://mentalized.net/journal/2019/09/13/ruby-2-3-rvm-and-openssl-1-0/)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't have that version of openssl installed, so `brew switch` doesn't work for me. However, if I run `brew install openssl@1.0.2s` that doesn't work, no formulae are found. Furthermore, the article you provided doesn't use brew. Is there anyway I can install openssl 1.0 with brew?

Comment: Well you can try to install `brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb` otherwise please check this page `https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635` I am also on latest mac OS and everything working fine, so probably you have openssl old version in your system `locate openssl` will help you.